# Parallely executing instance methods [PREVIOUSLY:multiprocessing - instance variable gets overwrite]

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

Pythonists,

Here is my class definition,

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num
        self.out_come = multiprocessing.Manager.list()

    def func1(self):
        for n in range(self.num):
            self.out_come.append(numpy.random.randn(1)[0])
        return self.out_come
```

I am instantiating:

```
obj_l = []
for lettr in list(string.ascii_uppercase)[:5]:
    lettr = Test(0.2) # Initiating the class
    obj_l.append(lettr)
```

And I want to run parallelly the instance method as follows:

```
proc = []
for n in range(len(obj_l)):
    proc.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=obj_l[n].func1, args=(param[n],))

for p in proc: p.start()
for p in proc: p.join()
```

However, When I try to access the outcome of the function `self.out_come`. I am getting the same result for all the objects. It looks like, `self.out_come` gets overwritten. Correct me if I am wrong and advise me how to run instance methods in parallel.

**EDIT-1:**

Looks like the issue is with `multiprocessing.Manager.list()`. Looking for ways to get this work. Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT-2:**

`multiprocessing.Manager.list()` is just a proxy to access the `self.out_come` instance of `Test` class. As it looks, this way I can only access the proxy and not each individual `self.out_come` instance.

I have tried another approach of using `Threading`. I am not able to achieve what I want: Each `self.out_come` get dealt separately. However, I did not get any speed up (due to GIL). Essentially, running serially without any parallelization.

I have tried using `multiprocessing.Queue` but with no success.

Any other suggestions/idea? (numba or cython)

Comment: Sounds like you're forgetting that each process can only have a copy, not an actual reference to the instance.

Comment: What is param, and why is your instantiation not in a comprehension? It looks like you're jumping through ridiculous hoops to achieve a trivial result.

Comment: Thanks @Mad Physicist. `param`  is the parameter that I am passing to the instance method. I am not able to think why should be using comprehension instead of what I am using, other than syntactic elegance. I, after surfing the web and reading, understood that child process does only copy the class and hence sending results back from child to parent, to me at least, is not trivial as I am a beginner. I am thankful, if you can advise me how can I address this.

Comment: Isn't the `multiprocessing.Queue` supposed to pass the results back to parent? Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: In the class you show, the method accepts no arguments. The code you've posted here seems inconsistent.

Comment: Oh my! Apologies. It was a typo when I tried to abstract. No param. Let me correct the code.

Comment: `obj_l = [Test(0.2) for _ in range(5)]`. What's the whole business with `list(string.ascii_uppercase)[:5]`?

Comment: Now I get that. I don't need to assign the objects to a variable, rather I can directly append the objects to a list. Thanks @Mad Physicist.

Comment: You don't need to jump through ten hoops to loop something five times. A regular for loop would work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue you're seeing is that all your processes share the same random seed, if I fix the bugs in your code and add a random seed to the distributed function, everything seems to work. Try commenting out the line with the random seed bellow and running it again.

```
import multiprocessing
import string
import numpy

class Test():
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num
        self.out_come = multiprocessing.Manager().list()

    def func1(self):
        numpy.random.seed(self.num)
        for n in range(self.num):    
            self.out_come.append(numpy.random.randn(1)[0])
        return self.out_come

obj_l = []
for s in range(1, 6):
    lettr = Test(s) # Initiating the class
    obj_l.append(lettr)

proc = []
for n in range(len(obj_l)):
    proc.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=obj_l[n].func1))

for p in proc:
  p.start()
for p in proc:
  p.join()

for i in obj_l:
    print(i.out_come)

# [1.6243453636632417]
# [-0.4167578474054706, -0.056266827226329474]
# [1.7886284734303186, 0.43650985051198943, 0.09649746807200862]
# [0.05056170714293955, 0.499951333237829, -0.9959089311068651, 0.6935985082913116]
# [0.44122748688504143, -0.33087015189408764, 2.43077118700778, -0.2520921296030769, 0.10960984157818278]
```

A few more things to keep in mind, you can't send a method to another process. What you're actually doing is sending the whole instance, then having the method called on that instance. I'd recommend writing your distributed functions as top level functions with explicit arguments, that way it's cleared what's being transmitted between Processes. It'll help in debugging :).

Lastly I'd highly recommend looking at `multiprocessing.Pool` and its `map` methods, especially `map_async` and `imap_unordered`. If you can express your workload as functions with explicit returns instead of stateful operations on shared objects, it'll both be easier to write your code & more performant in the long run.

Comment: Thank you @Bi Rico's. I think the caveats is, ` can't send a method to another process` . as rightly pointed out I am sending the instances and having the method call on the instance. I have tried the amended code, it returns a single list of outcome. What I wanted: since I am sending instances and having method to call on the instances, wouldn't I be getting list of lists or number of instances times the list? Correct me, if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: @RussellB Sorry, I don't quite follow your question. I believe the result you get is the same as the result you would get if you replace `Manger().list()` with `[]` and your remote call to `func1` with a local call to `func1`, are you expecting something different?

Comment: My question is: With multiple instances, what I expect is each instance to return an unique list of random numbers. After re-reading your answer, I think I should write distributed functions as top level "functions" and not as class methods to avoid issues such this. Correct me, if my understanding is wrong. I appreciate your efforts in helping me understand this

Comment: I believe your expectation, "each instance to return an unique list of random numbers" is exactly what's happening. Each instance in `obj_l` has a different list, when we print these lists they're different lengths and have different content.

Answer (score -1):

**Posting this as answer for the sake of completion:**

It looks like Python gives a hard time for those who want to execute their instance methods in parallel, if not impossible.

I have found a way to do so by using [CharmPy](https://charmpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). While this requires all your classes to be subclasses of `Chare` parent class, this is achievable, IMO.

It is written on top of `Charm++` a distributed computing platform written in C++, though.

For those, found this helpful, Cheers!!

Comment: Are you in any way affiliated with charmpy?

Comment: Also, this does not provide a usable (by anyone else I mean) answer to your question.

Comment: To the first one: I am not affiliated with CharmPy or the lab that develops.

Comment: To the second: if instance methods cannot be executed in parallel and results from all the instance method can be received trivially, this might be of use. That is what my intention was.